# Use virtualization to create a production/beta server on same hardware

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have one server, and I want to use some sort of software to split the server into two virtual machines, one for production and one for beta. Linux only please.

Is this possible?

Also, I do not want recommendations on why not to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any of the mainstream virtualisation products - free or otherwise - Xen, Virtualbox, VMWare server, VMWare ESXi etc. will let you do this. Your choice may be narrowed down by any specific hardware requirements - notably if you have any peripherals (especially USB devices like dongles or special peripherals) that need to work in the virtual OS as some are better at 'passthrough' from the real hardware than others.